# Could not import "sktime" library in quantconnect.com though quantconnect supports the library

Tags: python, importerror, sktime, quantconnect

Lately, I was working on time series forecasting on `QuantConnect`. In the documentation of `QuantConnect`, it is mentioned that it the coding environment supports `sktime` library (a python library) but when I tried importing the `sktime` ARIMA forecaster, it is giving the following error.
[image: 1]

Comment: Please post the error as text not an image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.